# C# List of names task

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, variables, program-entry-point

So im making a program for college in which i must Write a program that will store names into an array.
As a new name is entered it will be added to the end of the array. The user can keep adding names until they enter the dummy val-ue ‘exit’
Once this has been done the program will display any duplicate names.
E.g.
Enter name: Bill
Enter name: Mary
Enter name: Anisha
Enter name: Mary
Enter name: exit
Mary is a duplicate.

I should also try to show how many times each name was duplicated.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This program allows you to write names to a list,");
        int i = 0;

        //Due to the fact than i cannont resize an array after initialization, i used a list and converted it to an array at a later point
        List<string> names = new List<string>();


        string name = " ";
        Console.WriteLine("Enter names then press enter to add them to the list of names! if you wish to exit simple type exit.");
        //This loop adds names to the list
        while (name.ToLower() != "exit")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Name: ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            names.Add(name);
            i++;

        }

        //This line converts the list to an array
        string[] nameArray = names.ToArray();

        for(int z = 0;z <nameArray.Length + 1;z++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < z ; y++)
            {
                if (nameArray[y] == nameArray[z])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The name: " + nameArray[y] + " is a duplicate.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
            }

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
       }
```

This is my code but it crashes when I compare the names, it gives me one duplicate name and no others. and then crashes, i think it is relative to the second for loop but please could someone run this and help me out.

Comment: It seems its home work, isn't it ?

Comment: Yeah, but I need to use an array, its for college work

Comment: Also i wish to learn how arrays work

Comment: `names = new string[i];` at this line, i is 1. so the string array size is just 1. then you can access just 0-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array can not be resized after initialization. You'll have to use `List` instead of an array.

If you only want to use array, then you will have to fix its size at the time of initialization. You can ask the user to enter the array size. Or you can initialize a long length array (but its not recommended).

Comment: I actually found out what to do, if i declare the array in the while loop its size will change

Comment: No, it'll initialize a new array and your old values will be lost.

Comment: That would be super inefficient to re size or recreate an array every iteration

Comment: How to initialize a long array?

Comment: You can initialize 50 or 100 items array. But again I'll say its not recommended. Use **Mrinal Kamboj** code if its possible for you.

Answer (score 1):

Program is  incorrect, in fact this is a case for exception, since your initial value for i is 1 and your string [] is of size 1 so at most you can access index 0, in fact in the first loop itself you are trying index 1, which is out of range exception. Even if you correct that the logic is incorrect, the way it has been designed. Following is a better solution

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This program allows you to write names to a list,");:
        List<string> nameList = new List<string>();
        string name = " ";
        Console.WriteLine("Enter names then press enter to add them to the list of names! if you wish to exit simple type exit.");
        while (name.ToLower() != "exit")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Name: ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            nameList.Add(name);
        }
        string[] nameArray = nameList.ToArray();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

nameArray will be the array that you need as a response

Comment: @Shaharyar as per OP, the final result has to be in an array and in fact List uses array internally, it is re-sizable array. How would you otherwise re-size an array dynamically until and unless it is recreated in each iteration, which is extremely inefficient

Comment: @ Shaharyar irrespective of the acceptance, this is the efficient way. I cannot think of a better way using array